# Comparing changes over time using dates and colors

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Pretty lengthy title but essentially I have a table like this

[image]

and I want to find the delta between each data point and every other data point on the *same* row, for *each* row.

For example, for `26/03/2018`, I would want to get:

- `Red-Blue` (`5-2`),
- `Red-Green` (`5-4`),
- `Red-Purple` (`5-3`),
- `Red-N/A` (`N/A`),
- `Red-Yellow` (`5-5`),
- `Blue-Green` (`2-4`),
- `Blue-Purple` (`2-3`),
- etc.

I then want to repeat this over all the rows to see how the value of the difference in colour pairs changes over the dates, as shown in the table below.

[image]

So far I've tried doing this for one row by filling an array with a row and looping through it, outputting the result to another sheet, but I'm completely new to VBA and unfamiliar with the multitude of errors I get running this macro.

```
Public Sub ReadToArray()
Dim ForwardData As Variant
ForwardData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D8:GF8").Value
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim MaxVal As Integer
Dim SwapArray As Variant
MaxVal = UBound(ForwardData) - LBound(ForwardData) + 1
 For i = 1 To MaxVal
        For j = i + 1 To MaxVal
            SwapArray = ForwardData(i) - ForwardData(j)
        Next j
    Next i



Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D").Value = SwapArray

End Sub
```

So far my problems seem to be that

- I don't know how to loop between rows
- the N/A values throw up an error when I simply want any comparison with N/A involved to throw up N/A
- referring to a position in the created row array such as 'ForwardData(i)' creates an error

thanks for reading!

Comment: A couple things to note (that you should fix and then see where you end up): `j` is not defined, which you should always be in the habit of doing, and you have a `For...Loop` using `MaxVal` as the high end, yet `MaxVal` doesn't appear to be initialized with a value anywhere, so it stands as `0`. This in turn will cause your loop to not even run.

Comment: I found MaxVal using UBound - LBound +1 on the ForwardData array and also initialized j as an integer. Unfortunately, I still can't seem to avoid 'subscript out of range' and 'type mismatch' errors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post your updated code to your question and also let us know where you get your first error when stepping through with `F8`? Also, what exactly does `D8:GF8` encompass? You don't have headings on the images of your spreadsheets, so I don't know what you're attempting to assign `ForwardData` to.

Comment: I receive error 1008 'Application defined or object defined error' when running this macro. It highlights the 'Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D").Value = SwapArray' line. The table of colour-dates is a simplified example here. The D8:GF8 represents a row on my actual table. I filled a variant array named 'ForwardData' with the contents of that row, much like how a row on the colour-date table would be the numbers associated with Red, Blue, Green etc for a single date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code bellow will adjust automatically to more columns and rows (colors and dates)
The main anchor point is `topCell` so if your table starts at D8 update this line:

```
Set topCell = ws1.Cells(2, 2)    'B2
```

to

```
Set topCell = ws1.Cells(8, 4)    'D8
```

and that cell is expected to be empty.

To avoid any issues please create a new generic VBA module and paste this code in it

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowDelta()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, topCell As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2
    Set topCell = ws1.Cells(2, 2)       'Main cell - B2

    Dim ur1tbl As Range, ur1Arr As Variant
    Set ur1tbl = GetUsedRange(topCell)  'topCell should be empty
    If ur1tbl Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With ur1tbl
        Set topCell = .Cells(1)
        Set ur1tbl = .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1)
        ur1Arr = ur1tbl
    End With

    Dim hHdr1Rng As Range, vHdr1Rng As Range, hHdr2Arr As Variant, vHdr2Arr As Variant
    SetHeaders topCell, hHdr1Rng, vHdr1Rng      'updates hHdr1Rng and vHdr1Rng
    hHdr2Arr = GetDateHorizontalHeaders(vHdr1Rng)
    vHdr2Arr = GetColorVerticalHeaders(hHdr1Rng)

    Dim ws2hHdr As Range, ws2vHdr As Range, ur2rng As Range, ur2Arr As Variant
    SetWs2Areas ws2, topCell, hHdr2Arr, vHdr2Arr, ws2hHdr, ws2vHdr, ur2rng
    ws2hHdr = hHdr2Arr
    ws2vHdr = vHdr2Arr

    ur2Arr = ur2rng
    ur2Arr = GetDelta(ur1Arr, ur2Arr) 'updates ur2Arr
    ur2rng = ur2Arr
    ws2.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    ur2rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetUsedRange(ByRef firstCell As Range) As Range
    If Not firstCell Is Nothing Then
        Set GetUsedRange = firstCell.CurrentRegion   'Top-left cell (1st row & 1st col)
        If GetUsedRange.CountLarge = 1 Then
            Set GetUsedRange = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function SetHeaders(ByVal topCell As Range, _
                            ByRef hHdr As Range, _
                            ByRef vHdr As Range) As Boolean
    Dim hHdr1 As Range, hHdrMax As Long, vHdr1 As Range, vHdrMax As Long

    Set hHdr1 = topCell.Offset(0, 1)
    Set vHdr1 = topCell.Offset(1, 0)
    hHdrMax = hHdr1.End(xlToRight).Column
    vHdrMax = vHdr1.End(xlDown).Row
    With topCell.Parent
        Set hHdr = .Range(hHdr1, .Cells(topCell.Row, hHdrMax))
        Set vHdr = .Range(vHdr1, .Cells(vHdrMax, topCell.Column))
    End With
End Function

Private Function GetDateHorizontalHeaders(ByVal dtHdr As Range) As Variant
    Dim hHdr As Variant, vHdrMax As Long, i As Long

    vHdrMax = dtHdr.Rows.Count
    ReDim hHdr(1 To 1, 1 To vHdrMax)
    For i = 1 To vHdrMax
        hHdr(1, i) = IIf(IsError(dtHdr(i, 1)), "N/A", dtHdr(i, 1).Value2)
    Next
    GetDateHorizontalHeaders = hHdr
End Function
```

---

```
Private Function GetColorVerticalHeaders(ByVal clrHdr As Range) As Variant
    Dim vHdr As Variant, vHdrMax As Long, hHdrMax As Long

    hHdrMax = clrHdr.Columns.Count
    vHdrMax = hHdrMax * (hHdrMax - 1) \ 2   'max combinations
    ReDim vHdr(1 To vHdrMax, 1 To 1)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, val1 As String, val2 As String
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To hHdrMax
        For j = i + 1 To hHdrMax
            val1 = IIf(IsError(clrHdr(1, i)), "N/A", clrHdr(1, i).Value2)
            val2 = IIf(IsError(clrHdr(1, j)), "N/A", clrHdr(1, j).Value2)
            vHdr(k, 1) = val1 & " - " & val2
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    GetColorVerticalHeaders = vHdr
End Function
```

---

```
Private Function SetWs2Areas(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal topCell As Range, _
                             ByRef h As Variant, v As Variant, _
                             ByRef hHdr As Range, ByRef vHdr As Range, _
                             ByRef ur As Range) As Boolean
    Dim row1 As Long, col1 As Long, ws2TopLeft As Range, ws2BottomRight As Range
    Dim ws2BottomRightRow As Long, ws2BottomRightCol As Long

    col1 = topCell.Column
    row1 = topCell.Row

    With ws    'Sheet2 vertical and horizontal headers
        Set hHdr = .Range(.Cells(row1, col1 + 1), .Cells(row1, UBound(h, 2) + col1))
        Set vHdr = .Range(.Cells(row1 + 1, col1), .Cells(UBound(v) + row1, col1))
    End With

    Set ws2TopLeft = ws.Cells(hHdr.Row + 1, vHdr.Column + 1)

    ws2BottomRightRow = vHdr.Row + vHdr.Rows.Count - 1
    ws2BottomRightCol = hHdr.Column + hHdr.Columns.Count - 1

    Set ws2BottomRight = ws.Cells(ws2BottomRightRow, ws2BottomRightCol)

    Set ur = ws.Range(ws2TopLeft, ws2BottomRight)
End Function
```

---

```
Private Function GetDelta(ByVal ur1 As Variant, ByVal ur2 As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ur1Rows As Long, ur1Cols As Long, ur2Rows As Long, ur2Cols As Long

    ur1Rows = UBound(ur1, 1)
    ur1Cols = UBound(ur1, 2)

    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, c2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant

    r2 = 1
    c2 = 1

    For r1 = 1 To ur1Rows
        For i = 1 To ur1Cols
            For j = i + 1 To ur1Cols

                v1 = IIf(IsError(ur1(r1, i)), "N/A", ur1(r1, i))
                v2 = IIf(IsError(ur1(r1, j)), "N/A", ur1(r1, j))

                If IsNumeric(v1) And IsNumeric(v2) Then
                    ur2(r2, c2) = v1 - v2
                Else
                    ur2(r2, c2) = IIf(IsNumeric(v1), v2, v1)
                End If
                r2 = r2 + 1
            Next
        Next
        r2 = 1
        c2 = c2 + 1
    Next
    GetDelta = ur2
End Function
```

---

This is my test sheet (Sheet1)

[image: Sheet1]

And the results, on Sheet2

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Wow! This is incredible! I really like the more object orientated approach you've taken here. I achieved something similar with my code below, but I think your method is more flexible. I think I understand the majority of what your code is doing, but I get an error highlighting 'ReDim vHdr(1 To vHdrMax, 1 To 1)' when I run it, claiming that I run out of memory (even for small sets). The dataset I'm doing this for also produces over 3 million data points (including N/A values) so I worry that the multiple loops will freeze the program.

Comment: Nevermind! It works perfectly! The memory error was just a formatting issue going from browser -> excel. The code is ideal and runs far faster than mine. I need to change the GetHorizontal and GetVertical header functions as the actual table has dates for both, but apart from that its perfect. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I first find the last occupied row and column, then loop through the table itself using a counter to create the Deltas. These are then output onto a table much like the example above.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim Col As Long
 Dim Row As Long
 Dim Col1 As Long
 Dim Row1 As Long
 Dim Counter As Long

 'Find the last used row in a Column in Sheet1
Dim LastRow As Long
With Sheet1
     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
 End With
 'Find the last used column in a Row in Sheet1
Dim LastCol As Integer
With Sheet1
    LastCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

Counter = 4
For Col = 4 To LastCol
    For Col1 = Col To LastCol - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Counter, 4) = Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, Col), "mm/dd/yyyy") + "-" + Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, Col1 + 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next Col1
Next Col

Counter = 4
For Row = 5 To LastRow
    For Col = 4 To LastCol - 1
        For Col1 = Col To LastCol - 1
            If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, Col)) And IsNumeric(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, Col1 + 1)) Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Counter, Row) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, Col) - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, Col1 + 1)
            Else
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Counter, Row) = "N/A"
            End If
            Counter = Counter + 1
        Next Col1
    Next Col
    Counter = 4
Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can spot anything inefficient in this code please let me know. Your code clocks in at 9 seconds to generate 3 million data points whereas mine takes upwards of 4 minutes :/

Comment: Great - this is the same as mine (GetDelta) but simplified. The difference in performance is caused by the interaction with the Range objects like `Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)` or `Sheet1.Range("A1")`. Your code reads data from the sheet one cell at the time. The most important improvement in performance in VBA is working with arrays instead of ranges. My answer uses arrays so is faster but there is a bit more effort involved. To get the first row of data into an array you need to declare a Variant variable, then assign the entire range to it. Process the array then assign the array back to the range

Comment: Example of array: `Dim arr as Variant: arr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows(1)`. Now change the first cell in the array: `arr(1, 1) = "Test Value"`. At the end move the array back to the range: `Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows(1) = arr`. When you start working with array you'll see much better performance